# paginating through a CRUD API

Tags: javascript, pagination, socket.io, sails.js

I am writing a client that will query a CRUD web API. I will be be using `socket.io.get('/api')`. Problem is: I want to paginate the results, so I can start displaying stuff while my client is still receiving the data.

The results from the API come as JSON, like

```
[
  {
    "id": "216754",
    "date": "2015-07-30T02:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": "216755",
    "date": "2015-08-30T02:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

The api lets me construct an URL query where I can limit the size of each result array. So I can make a query like `/api&skip=10&limit=10`, and it will get me the results from item 10 to item 19. What I want to be able to do is to **keep looping** and receiving results **until the results array is less than length = 10** (that will mean we reached the end of the dataset). And I need that to be asynchronous, so I can start to work on the data right from the start and update whatever work I have done each time a new page is received.

Comment: But, there are no promises in your code nor a clear idea of what you're trying to do with promises.  Plus, you can't loop with a `while` statement over an async operation anyway.  Can you back up to the very beginning and describe what problem you're trying to solve because the code in your current approach is not helping understand what you want to achieve. Please write a mini-spec for what you're trying to achieve, independent of any code you've written so far or any problems you encountered in that code. We need a clean description of the desired interface or problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @jfriend00, is this clearer? :)

Comment: `until the results array is less than length = 20 (that will mean we reached the end of the dataset)` - if you;re getting only 10 at a time as per `/api&skip=10&limit=10` then you'll stop after the first chunk of data anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks for the correction. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it an infinite scroll that you are trying to do? Or do you want to call all the pages asynchronously and be able to receive the page 3 before page 2? Reading the question, I understand it is the second.

**You can't rely on *"until the results array is less than length = 10"* since you want to launch all the calls at the same time.**

You should do **a first query to retrieve the number of records**. Then you will be able to know how many pages there are, you could generate all the urls that you need and call them asynchronously.

It could looks like this (code not tested):

```
var nbItemsPerPage = 10;

socket.io.get(
  '/api/count',  // <= You have to code the controller that returns the count
  function(resCount) {
    nbPages = resCount / nbItemsPerPage;
    for (var i=0; i<nbPages; i++) {
      // Javascript will loop without waiting for the responses
      (function (pageNum) {
        socket.io.get(
          '/api',
          {skip:nbItemsPerPage*pageNum, limit=nbItemsPerPage},
          function (resGet) {
            console.log('Result of page ' + pageNum + ' received');
            console.log(resGet);
          }
      )(i);  // <= immediate function, passing "i" as an argument
             // Indeed, when the callback function will be executed, the value of "i" will have changed
             // Using an immediate function, we create a new scope to store pageNum for every loop
    }
  }
)
```

---

If what you are trying to archive is an infinite scroll page, then you have to load the page *n+1* only after you received the content of the page *n* and you can rely on `results.length < 10`

Comment: I had not thought about launching all the calls at the same time, but I like it! Can you show some pseudocode for achieving this? I am just starting to understand asynchronous programming.

Comment: Because the calls are asynchronous, they will append the same time if you don't use callbacks or a library like `async`. I added a code sample.